# image Popup not working. what is the problem?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have created a aHTML file, and a image popup, but it not working...
This result is just took from Google Search.

I have tried to solve it many times but I couldn't.

here is my code..

You can run it in CodePen: [**Open**](https://codepen.io/adyou2/pen/yLJgeqp)

```
<html>

<head>

</head>
<style>
    .image-link {
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
  cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}


/* This block of CSS adds opacity transition to background */

.mfp-with-zoom .mfp-container,
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready .mfp-container {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing .mfp-container,
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* padding-bottom and top for image */

.mfp-no-margins img.mfp-img {
  padding: 0;
}


/* position of shadow behind the image */

.mfp-no-margins .mfp-figure:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}


/* padding for main container */

.mfp-no-margins .mfp-container {
  padding: 0;
}


/* aligns caption to center */

.mfp-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
}

.image-source-link {
  color: #DDD;
}

body {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-family: "Calibri", "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}


</style>
<body>
    
    <h2>Magnific Popup: image zoom effect</h2>




    <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Anthochaera_chrysoptera.jpg/800px-Anthochaera_chrysoptera.jpg" class="without-caption image-link">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Anthochaera_chrysoptera.jpg/800px-Anthochaera_chrysoptera.jpg" width="172" height="115" />
    </a>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Water_Dolphin.jpg/800px-Water_Dolphin.jpg" data-source="http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Picture_of_the_day" class="with-caption image-link" title="The caption">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Water_Dolphin.jpg/800px-Water_Dolphin.jpg" width="172" height="105" />
    </a>
    







    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
$('.without-caption').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  closeOnContentClick: true,
  closeBtnInside: false,
  mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
  image: {
    verticalFit: true
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
  }
});

$('.with-caption').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  closeOnContentClick: true,
  closeBtnInside: false,
  mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
  image: {
    verticalFit: true,
    titleSrc: function(item) {
      return item.el.attr('title') + ' &middot; <a class="image-source-link" href="' + item.el.attr('data-source') + '" target="_blank">image source</a>';
    }
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true
  }
});


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the actual problem is. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Primarily, please explain what exactly your code _should_ do and how exactly it currently fails

Comment: try this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the following inside `head tag`, The reason is the plugin has not been appended here and for that reason it is not working for codepen to work you must have to add it as resources in respective section

```
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css">

<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

The codepen example you can follow https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/details/aKwxt

Comment: can i remove the code `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @EliotAlderson Sure you can its just the same as mentioned above, only updated version used here
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>